# Python Confusion with Modules not being found

Tags: python, import, error-handling, module, version

I am super confused as to why some python module are not recognized when importing but when I try installing they show "Requirements already Satisfied". I am confused as the same notebook show 2 different version for 2 commands why from what I know is supposed to show the version of python active at the moment no? But it stays the same even when I change the path hierarchy what am I doing wrong or how can I fix this ?

I need to use the imblearn module for a project but im stuck with this now. Had the same problem when I tried importing plotly and couldn't make it work either but plotly wasn't too important for the project so I ignored it.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong or what the issue is and any suggestions to fix?

TIA
Images for ref below

[Here Python 3.10 path is at the top hierarchy but check the notebook results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNcao.png)

[Python 3.11 on this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM352.png)

And I did restart cmd and Jupyter Lab for each time

Comment: Your Jupyter notebook is running out of a different interpreter than the one corresponding to `python` and `pip` on the command line. Compare `print(sys.executable)` with `!type python` or `!where.exe python`

Comment: HI, ty for rep,
I tried `print(sys.executable)` it returns "C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe"
and `!type python` returns "The system cannot find the file specified." and `!where.exe python` returns "c:\Users\BooolZay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python310\python.exe
c:\program files\python311\python.exe
C:\Users\BooolZay\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"
still not sure what to do.

Comment: I just uninstalled both versions and installed anaconda instead and its working now, tho new problems rose but those are atm neglectable